# php - SimpleXMLElement insert xml content

Tags: php, xml

Say, I have the following php code:

```
<?php

$resultXML = "<root><book></book></root>"; 
$resultXML = new SimpleXMLElement($resultXML);

?>
```

How can I insert the following `XML`: `<car><bmw></bmw></car>` such that I get `<root><car><bmw></bmw></car><book></book></root>`

Basically, I want to generic solution to insert an element (with its children, grandchildren etc) in an existing `XML`. Any help?

Comment: It'd be interesting to see your attempts so we can help you identify what went wrong.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario  One way is to loop through the `xml` I want to insert and use `SimpleXMLElement::addChild` to add each element and its children (hard way and does not scale well). Another way I can think of is to use string manipulation and insert the second `xml` after `<root>`. This does not look like a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$resultXML = new SimpleXMLElement('<root><book></book></root>');

            $car=$resultXML->addChild('car');

            $car->addChild('bmw');
            $resultXML->asXML('path/to/save/abc.xml');
```

Comment: `Basically, I want to generic solution to insert an element (with its children, grandchildren etc) in an existing XML.` Your answer assumes that I know the content of the XML I want to insert.